# Why running coroutine on Dispatcher.Main and Dispatcher.Default returns same result?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Code:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import kotlin.system.*

fun main() = runBlocking {
    val time = measureTimeMillis {
        println("Outside of child coroutine: ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
        runBlocking() {
            delay(1000)
            println("Inside of child coroutine: ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
        } 
        println("After child coroutine...")
    }
    println("Time: ${time}.ms")
}
```

Output when running child runBlocking without any dispatcher:

```
Outside of child coroutine: main @coroutine#1
Inside of child coroutine: main @coroutine#2
After child coroutine...
Time: 1010.ms
```

Output when running child runBlocking with Dispatchers.Default:

```
Outside of child coroutine: main @coroutine#1
Inside of child coroutine: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1 @coroutine#2
After child coroutine...
Time: 1027.ms
```

I know runBlocking blocks the calling thread, or if we replace `runBlocking` with `launch` code will not blocked. My question is  **why we are using dispatchers?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, that's not Dispatchers.Main. It's the `main` *function*'s thread being used for the single-threaded internal Dispatcher of `runBlocking`. There's no UI thread in your app, so there is no Dispatchers.Main.

Nothing in your code is doing anything in parallel with `launch` or `async`, so you are doing everything sequentially, regardless of which Dispatchers and threads are being used.

If you change the inner `runBlocking` to `launch`, then it will be run in parallel, but if you don't use Dispatchers.Default for it, it will still be using the same thread from the main function. However, the child coroutine will suspend during the `delay()` call which allows that single thread to run the other parts of the coroutine before it is reused again to resume the child coroutine.

Basically, since you don't have any blocking code, you won't notice any significant difference in the time it takes to complete the work using one thread versus multiple threads.

If you were doing some slow, blocking work, you would notice the difference between using a multi-threaded Dispatcher versus using only the `runBlocking` thread`. Try the following with and without the` Dispatchers.Default`.

```
fun main() = runBlocking {
    val time = measureTimeMillis {
        println("Outside of child coroutine: ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
        val job = launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
            Thread.sleep(1000L) // simulate blocking work
            println("Inside of child coroutine: ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
        }  
        Thread.sleep(500L)
        println("After child coroutine...")
        job.join()
        println("Waited for child coroutine...")
    }
    println("Time: ${time}.ms")
}
```

Comment: I tried your code but there is no difference between using it with or without Dispatchers.Default (tried at kotlin playground

Comment: Sorry, try it now. Need to put blocking work inside and outside the child coroutine to be able to demonstrate how the multithreaded Dispatcher will use parallelism.